# Delete from array with reindex - AS3.0

Tags: actionscript

I would like to delete a item from my array and still have the same index for every item afterwards.

Example

```
var arr:Array = new Array();
arr[1] = 'One';
arr[2] = 'Two';
arr[3] = 'Three';

arr.splice(2, 1);

for(var index in arr) {
    trace(index+':'+arr[index]);
}
```

Outputs:

```
1:One
2:Three
```

And should ouput

```
1:One
3:Three
```

Anyone that could help me a little bit here? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

Instead of using a array, i'll use a object to hold my items. Like this

```
var objArr = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three'};
```

And when I delete i do like this.

```
delete objArr[1];
```

I know I wont get the array functions then. But in my case I don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

If you splice an element from an array then the array is refreshed and the elements after that index is moved to fill that index.

If you really want to have the elements in the same index always then do assign the index with empty string instead of splicing it.

Try this:

```
array[1] = "";
```

instead of,

```
array.splice(1, 1);
```

According to me splicing is a good way of practicing.

Comment: I have to delete the item, not just set it as null. But thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: But remember when deleting you won't have the items in the same index as it is in before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [delete](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#delete) operator:

```
var arr:Array = new Array();
arr[1] = 'One';
arr[2] = 'Two';
arr[3] = 'Three';

delete arr[2];

for(var index in arr) {
    trace(index+':'+arr[index]);
}
```

Comment: This will leave it undefined. That is not what i looking for. Sorry. But thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: Hmm. I can't get what do you need then. What are you going to receive with `trace(arr[2])` after your code?

Comment: I have posted a answer with my solution :-)